# Unable to resize the reference VM once the lab has been created

Tags: rest, api, azure-lab-services

In Azure Lab Services, the Classroom Labs, I cannot resize the reference VM once the lab has been created. I need this because I've fully configured a reference VM and now have released that I require to bump the spec of the VM from Standard to Performance.

The [labs portal UI](https://labs.azure.com/) doesn't expose this functionality, nor does the [Az.LabsServices](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab/tree/master/samples/ClassroomLabs/Modules/Library) posh module. 
I've tried saving my changes into an image in a Shared gallery and then reference that image on creating a new lab with the new specs. The problem with this new lab was that the machine didn't inherit all of the registry modifications and main user settings from the saved image.
Unless there is a specific undocumented reason why these VM can't be resized, they should adhere to the REST endpoint capabilities described in [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/labservices/environmentsettings/update). The API calls that I've tried are various combinations of following:

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups
/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.LabServices/labaccounts
/{labAccountName}/labs/{labName}/environmentsettings
/{environmentSettingName}?api-version=2018-10-15
```

or newer endpoint

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups
/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.LabServices/labaccounts
/{labAccountName}/labs/{labName}/environmentsettings
/{environmentSettingName}?api-version=2019-01-01-preview
```

Where `{environmentSettingName}` was either set to `default` or `properties.resourceSettings`
And the payload varying from `{"properties":{"resourceSettings":{"size":"Performance"}}}` or `{"resourceSettings":{"size":"Performance"}}`
and other combinations

The only response I am getting from the API is
"The operation is not supported"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately resizing the template VM is not supported. Shared image gallery only supports generalized images which requires sysprep and hence the settings are lost. We will take this scenario as a feature suggestion.